# How to create array of object from HTML Table in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I create an array of objects from an HTML table body? This is how my HTML looks like

```html
<tbody id="metadata">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="numeric" /></td>
    <td><input type="numeric" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="numeric" /></td>
    <td><input type="numeric" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="numeric" /></td>
    <td><input type="numeric" /></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

here is what I tried this javascript to get all the values from the table cell in an array of objects. I don't understand why my `cMetadata` always return a blank array

```js
let cMetadata;
if (document.querySelectorAll("metadata")) {
  let tableData = document.querySelectorAll("metadata");
  cMetadata = [...tableData].map((row) => {
    return {
      altions: row.cells[0].textContent,
      lexity: row.cells[1].textContent,
    };
  });
}
```

final array of object should look like

```
cMetadata = [{altions: 1 , lexity: 2},{altions: 2 , lexity: 2},{altions: 3 , lexity: 2}]
```

Comment: Using `.querySelectorAll()` for such trivial queries only hurts the performance of your app, `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementsByTagName()` would work faster.

Comment: assuming your `tableData` variable has to store `<tbody>`-node, you got missing '#' and are supposed to use `.querySelector()` (not 'all'). I.e. `.document.querySelector('#metadata')`

Comment: Once captured `<tbody>` you need to do further nested queries to capture `<tr>`, `<td>` nodes (to drill down to the values of nested `<input>`-nodes)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - What, in precise time, is the performance deficit? IMO your comment is too pedantic and will have what amounts to almost zero impact on the performance of this code. (Most likely in the sub-microsecond range on even the most constrained CPU.

Comment: i already tried that ```.document.querySelector('#metadata')``` but its not working

Comment: @RandyCasburn: microseconds sum up to second... repeating the same wasteful pattern over and over again may give cumulative effect, especially for heavy-loaded apps, aren't you agree?

Comment: @PURU : *'...not working'* because you used that in a wrong way

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - you didn’t answer my query - in order to back up your assertion, how much time is wasted precisely? Rather, you chose to answer anecdotally. Either you don’t _really_ know or you are parroting someone else’s opinion. Either way, your comment is unsupported and misplaced here. Also, this is not the place to discuss this futher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verified that you have the `tbody` node inside a `table` node. You can get the items with `document.querySelectorAll("#metadata tr")`:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#metadata tr");
  const result = Array.from(elements).map(tr => {
    const childs = tr.querySelectorAll("input");
    return {
      p1: childs[0].value,
      p2: childs[1].value
    };
  });

  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="metadata">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="numeric"></td>
      <td><input type="numeric"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="numeric"></td>
      <td><input type="numeric"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="numeric"></td>
      <td><input type="numeric"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Get Data</button>
```

Comment: A good answer, could probably use some explanation. But I struggled with the fact the OP provided no elements within the rows that have text content. The only thing there are input elements. Yet the OP’s code suggests otherwise. OP should clarify the question a bit.

Comment: This always gives me undefined value when I have vale inside of input box

Comment: That is because the code is only called once at the beginning of the snippet, you should put it in a function that runs on a button press or on change of the fields.

Comment: i put this in function  then only I tried

Comment: I would generally advise against hard coding the DOM in your JS though: if you add other elements in your `<td>` it suddenly doesn't work anymore without there being red flags that you shouldn't alter the structure.